# Escape & character with DocuSign Custom Button

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I have a button that I created but I'm having issues with it working when Account Name has the & symbol in it.  When & is added, it completely clears out the rest of email subject.  I tried adding a JSENCODE and that didn't solve the problem.  Is there another way that I can get this to work?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 

//Adding Notes & Attachments 
var LA='0'; 

//Custom Email Subject 
var CES='Re: Agreement for On-Site Mobile Services from TestCompany, Inc.:'; 

//Custom Email Message 
var CEM='{!JSENCODE(Account.Name)}\\n{!Contact.Name}\\n{!JSENCODE(Contact.MailingStreet)}\\n{!Contact.MailingCity}, {!Contact.MailingState} {!Contact.MailingPostalCode}\\n\\nRe: Agreement for On-Site Mobile Services\\n\\nPlease find attached our Agreement for Services (agreement) for {!Opportunity.Account}. The Agreement outlines the services to be provided by TestCompany, fee schedule and our general terms and conditions for your review and electronic signature.\\n\\nOn behalf of TestCompany, we look forward to the opportunity to serve your organization.\\n\\n{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}\\n{!Opportunity.OwnerTitle}\\nexaminetics\\n{!Opportunity.Owner_Street_Address__c}\\n{!Opportunity.Owner_Address__c}\\n{!Opportunity.OwnerPhone}\\n{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail}\\nwww.testcompany.com'; 


//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ampersands are characters outside the ASCII set. Since the custom button logic is pushing this data through a URL, try URLENCODING in addition to JSENCODE.

Example:

CEM="{!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(Account.Name))}

I would recommend applying this for all your merge fields.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.  It still cut off the rest of the email subject.  Is there some type of find and replace hacking i could do for the string?   So if the string finds &, it would replace it with the word and?